# jQuery Validation - display only one message

Tags: asp.net, jquery-validation-engine

Using jQuery Validation Engine, how do I display only one message in the prompt when using regex?

I am using the jQuery validation engine in asp.net

[image: This is what I am seeing when I add new regex]

I wanted to hide 'This field is required' message and display the message from regex.

Comment: how are you hooking it all up, post some code

Answer (score 0):

You can give some default value to the field and it will not display "This field is required" message. Check example, http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoRegExp.html